# php 7.0 doesn't file upload

Tags: php, upload

I upload file by php, I can upload 1mb mp4 video but more than size, it can't upload.

I went to `php.ini`(`/etc/php/7.0/php.ini`) and replace such of it

```
file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 40M

post_max_size = 50M

max_execution_time = 300

memory_limit = 128M
```

then save&exit and restart apache.

But it still I can upload only 1mb video and can't upload big size video.

If you know about it please help me

Comment: Have you checked whatever changes you have done are applied or not? Please check phpinfo().

Comment: @JigneshPatel Thanks, it's my mistake. I change another php.ini file so I fix it.